# How do I find city type in Google Autocomplete API?

Tags: google-maps

I'm retrieving Google autocomplete data in JSON format, and I'm keen to know in which Object Array does Google sends "City" data because when I analyze the address types sometimes the city is found in post_town other times it is found in locality, sub-locality, administrative_area_level_1, administrative_area_level_2, administrative_area_level_3, administrative_area_level_4, administrative_area_level_5 .

The reason to find the city in correct type is that I need to write a code where I'll be using Google-type to identify the city and then storing into my database.

Can someone please help me identify to solve this issue?

Note: If you see the image below the city is identified in type: postal_town:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIuX6.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZkWk.png)

Comment: How the city is categorized will depend on the country for which the data applies.  Storing data other than the placeId of responses from the Google Places API is against the Terms of Use (however IANAL).

Comment: @geocodezip Where is the doc? How do I find out how the city is categorized in the United kingdom?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no complete documentation about address components structure based on each country.

The only place I know in the documentation that mentions address components for cities is the following page

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

It reads

> the sample code selects the *locality* component, which often represents the city part of the address. Examples of how components can differ include:
>
> - In the **UK** and in Sweden, the component to display the city is **postal_town**.
> - In Japan, components differ across prefectures.
> - Brooklyn and other parts of New York City do not include the city as part of the address. Instead, they use sublocality_level_1.

For other countries you should figure it out yourself based on the Google Maps API responses.

I hope my answer clarifies your doubt.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @xomena. I appreciate your time but again I still have concerns with the answer. Because if you look here: https://prnt.sc/p70gov. Google returned "London" as a locality, and we all know "London" is a city, so in this case, according to the Google developer guidelines, it should be postal_town, no?

Comment: It looks like the documentation is outdated in this case. Try to reach out to the Google Maps API technical support team via https://console.developers.google.com/google/maps-apis/support. They should be able to address your doubt. We outside Google don't have enough info.